# Recover a gitlab repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a gitlab installation with some data missing from database (don't ask me how, I've got it already broken).
I found repository, it looks like a .git directory

```
total 40
 0 drwxr-sr-x  2 openvpn polkitd     6 Nov  3  2021 refs
20 -rw-r--r--  1 openvpn polkitd 17832 Nov  1  2021 packed-refs
 0 drwxr-sr-x 34 openvpn polkitd   330 Nov  1  2021 objects
 0 drwxr-sr-x  2 openvpn polkitd    33 Oct 26  2021 info
 0 drwxr-sr-x  2 openvpn polkitd     6 Oct 20  2021 gitlab-worktree
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 openvpn polkitd   149 Oct 20  2021 config
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 openvpn polkitd  3008 Oct  7  2021 language-stats.cache
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 openvpn polkitd    23 Oct  7  2021 HEAD
 4 drwxr-sr-x  2 openvpn polkitd  4096 Oct  7  2021 hooks
 0 drwxr-sr-x  2 openvpn polkitd     6 Oct  7  2021 branches
 4 -rw-r--r--  1 openvpn polkitd    73 Oct  7  2021 description
```

Can I somehow recover files from it? Just renaming it to .git resulted in error, git does not recognize it as a repo.

Comment: what is the output if you place yourself on that directory and run `git branch` or something like that?